# Disable grub boot menu parameters editing while booting

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

Need some help. I have tried googling a lot but didn't find any solution. Normally while booting we can edit the boot parameters of grub. Using this we can login to machine as root without entering root password. below is a screenshot of example of this.

[image]

So, I don't want grub to let anyone edit these parameters. I want to disable the editing completely. I know if I lost my root password , i can forget the system but still, i want to disable the editing of parameters. my grub version is  2.02+dfsg1-6kali1.  You know how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer. Reading grub documentation I think I found the answer:

According to
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Authentication-and-authorisation.html

> Superusers are permitted to use the GRUB command line, edit menu entries, and execute any menu entry. If ‘superusers’ is set, then use of the command line and editing of menu entries are automatically restricted to superusers. **Setting ‘superusers’ to empty string effectively disables both access to CLI and editing of menu entries**.

So I think the answer is adding this to your grub.cfg:

```
set superusers=""
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are asking the wrong question.

If you manage to disable GRUB2 command line editing, you also need to modify your PC's firmware (BIOS/UEFI) to not allow booting etc. from a USB stick. In addition to that, you need a self-encrypting drive (or someone could just put it into another PC) or at least something like encrypted LVs.

There is an old rule: *Physical access equals complete compromise modulo time*

My recommendation for a secure device is to understand, where the security boundaries are: The boot process? The OS installation? Your personal data?

On my laptop I use an encrypted home directory and an additional encrypted partition, everything important is stored there and linked or bind-mounted to where it belongs.

**EDIT**

Even if I consider it security theater (a.o.t. real security), here is how to set up GRUB2 editing passwords:

In the GRUB conf headers:

```
set superusers="usera"
password usera passwordA
```

Comment: I got your point. USB booting is already disabled. you said "If you manage to disable GRUB2 command line editing..." is it possible? How can it be done?

Comment: What did you do about CMOS reset (to clear the USB boot issue), CDROM-boot, and attaching the drive to a different computer?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I know there are other ways to compromise but , lets just focus on disabling GRUB2 command line editing. i just want to know if it is possible. if possible then how?

Comment: As I edited into my answer, you just set up a password for superuser stuff such as editing. Be advised, that this gives you no security benefit at all.

Comment: so, will it disable grub2 cmd line editing?

Comment: It will set up a password for grub superuser functions, which include editing. This ofcourse is completly irrelevant to security.

Comment: @EugenRieck -- it is related to security, otherwise why have a password feature? Plus you're assuming there is complete physical access, which I don't think you can make that assumption. Think Kiosks -- they can be rebooted, but there isn't physical access to plug in peripherals or perform a CMOS reset. So, securing grub does become a relevant step and is completely relevant to security...

Comment: Where this answer is wrong is when systems have a [TPM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trusted_Platform_Module). These are not 100% bullet proof, but they will stop most attackers gaining access to your data. Both windows and Macos both seal encryption keys in a TPM. If you seal you encryption keys in a TPM then it can be configured to unseal as long as a previously created [standalone grub](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/grub/grub-mkstandalone.1.en) was booted (that untampered version and nothing else!). I'm holding back on a down vote but really I think this answer is wrong.